# Why am I getting %7Busername%7D at the end of my URL

Tags: php, laravel

Okay so for some reason I am getting: localhost/new_laravel_social_site/public/user/%7Busername%7D

I should be getting this:
localhost/new_laravel_social_site/public/user/username

There is a lot of code for this, but I am doing the codecoarse laravel social media site. I am clicking on people in my timeline and this comes up. But if I click their profile then it works just fine. I will post the code where it is breaking.

It is breaking where I have {{ $reply->user->getNameOrUsername() }}. I have everything working it is something with me using the $reply.

Edit: all routes are now on the bottom.

```
  @foreach ($statuses as $status)
          <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index'), ['username' => $status->user->username] }}">
                <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src=" {{ $status->user->getAvatarUrl(40) }}">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index'), ['username' => $status->user->username] }}">{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
                <p>{{ $status->body }}</p>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  @if ($status->created_at->diffInMonths(\Carbon\Carbon::now()) >= 1)
                    <li>{{ $status->created_at->format('j M Y, g:ia') }}</li>
                  @else
                    <li>{{ $status->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                  @endif
                    <li><a href="#">Like</a></li>
                    <li>10 likes</li>
                </ul>
                @foreach ($status->replies as $reply)
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username'=> $reply->user->username]) }}">
                        <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $reply->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $reply->user->getAvatarUrl(30) }}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $reply->user->username]) }}">{{ $reply->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h5>
                        <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                          @if ($reply->created_at->diffInMonths(\Carbon\Carbon::now()) >= 1)
                            <li>{{ $reply->created_at->format('j M Y, g:ia') }}</li>
                          @else
                            <li>{{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                          @endif
                            <li><a href="#">Like</a></li>
                            <li>4 likes</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
                <form role="form" action="{{ route('status.reply', ['statusId' => $status->id]) }}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has("reply-{$status->id}") ? ' has-error': '' }}">
                        <textarea name="reply-{{ $status->id }}" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Reply to this status"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has("reply-{$status->id}"))
                          <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first("reply-{$status->id}")}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
        {!! $statuses->render() !!}
@foreach ($status->replies as $reply)
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' =>  $user->username]) }}">
                        <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $reply->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $reply->user->getAvatarUrl(30) }}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $reply->user->username]) }}">{{ $reply->user->username }}</a></h5>
                        <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                          @if ($reply->created_at->diffInMonths(\Carbon\Carbon::now()) >= 1)
                            <li>{{ $reply->created_at->format('j M Y, g:ia') }}</li>
                          @else
                            <li>{{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</li>
                          @endif
                            <li><a href="#">Like</a></li>
                            <li>4 likes</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

Models

Stat.php:

```
<?php

namespace Chatty\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Status extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'statuses';

  protected $fillable = [
    'body'
  ];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Chatty\Models\User', 'user_id');
  }

  public function scopeNotReply($query)
  {
    return $query->whereNull('parent_id');
  }

  public function replies()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Chatty\Models\Status', 'parent_id');
  }

}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace Chatty\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract

{
    use Authenticatable;


    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
      'username',
      'email',
      'password',
      'confirm_password',
      'first_name',
      'last_name',
      'location',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
      'password',
      'confirm_password',
      'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getName()
    {
      if($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
      }

      if($this->first_name) {
        return $this->first_name;
      }

      return  null;
    }

    public function getNameOrUsername()
    {
      return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
    }

    public function getFirstNameOrUsername()
    {
      return $this->first_name ?: $this->username;
    }

    public function getAvatarUrl($size)
    {
      return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md($this->email) }}?d=mm&s=$size";
    }

    public function statuses()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('Chatty\Models\Status', 'user_id');
    }

    public function friendsOfMine()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Chatty\Models\User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
    }

    public function friendOf()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Chatty\Models\User', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function friends()
    {
      return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get()->merge($this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get());
    }

    public function friendRequest()
    {
      return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', false)->get();
    }

    public function friendRequestPending()
    {
      return $this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted', false)->get();
    }

    public function hasFriendRequestPending(User $user)
    {
      return (bool) $this->friendRequestPending()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
    }

    public function hasFriendRequestRecieved(User $user)
    {
      return (bool) $this->friendRequest()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
    }

    public function addFriend(User $user)
    {
      $this->friendOf()->attach($user->id);
    }

    public function acceptFriendRequest(User $user)
    {
      $this->friendRequest()->where('id', $user->id)->first()->pivot->
      update([
        'accepted' => true,
      ]);
    }
```

Relevant Routes:

```
Route::post('/status/{statusId}/reply', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\StatusController@postReply',
  'as' => 'status.reply',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::get('/user/{username}', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
  'as' => 'profile.index',
]);
```

Here is the method inside my StatusController I am using:

```
public function postReply(Request $request, $statusId)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
      "reply-{$statusId}" => 'required|max:1000',
    ], [
      'required' => 'You must have content to reply',
    ]);


    $status = Status::notReply()->find($statusId);

    if(!$status) {
      return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    if(!Auth::user()->isFriendsWith($status->user) && Auth::user()->id !== $status->user->id) {
      return redirect()
        ->route('home')
        ->with('info', 'Must be a friend to reply to this status, or be signed in');
    }

      $reply = Status::create([
        'body' => $request->input("reply-{$statusId}"),
      ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

      $status->replies()->save($reply);

      return redirect()->back()->with('info',"Reply has been comented!");


  }
```

All Routes:

```
<?php

/**
* Home
**/

Route::get('/', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
  'as' => 'home',
]);


/*
* Authentication
*/

Route::get('/signup', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignup',
  'as' => 'auth.signup',
  'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::post('/signup', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignup',
  'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::get('/signin', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignin',
  'as' => 'auth.signin',
  'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::post('/signin', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignin',
  'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::get('/signout', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignout',
  'as' => 'auth.signout',
]);

/*
* search
*/

Route::get('/search', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getResults',
  'as' => 'search.results',
]);

/*
* Profiles
*/

Route::get('/user/{username}', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
  'as' => 'profile.index',
]);

Route::get('/profile/edit', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getEdit',
  'as' => 'profile.edit',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::post('/profile/edit', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@postEdit',
  'as' => 'profile.edit',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

/*
* friends
*/

Route::get('/friends', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\FriendController@getIndex',
  'as' => 'friends.index',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::get('/friends/add/{username}', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\FriendController@getAdd',
  'as' => 'friends.add',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::get('/friends/accept/{username}', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\FriendController@getAccept',
  'as' => 'friends.accept',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

/*
* Statuses
*/

Route::post('/status', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\StatusController@postStatus',
  'as' => 'status.post',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::post('/status/{statusId}/reply', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\StatusController@postReply',
  'as' => 'status.reply',
  'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

Comment: If you need more code please just let me know what you need =]

Answer (score 1):

For googlers ... in my case was an extra } at the end of my route....

Was

```
Route::get('url/{uuid}}', function ($uuid) {
```

Instead of

```
Route::get('url/{uuid}', function ($uuid) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code too much I have seen that error before. But without giving an answer can you show all the routes of the project.

The error is usually you have 2 of the same routes.

```
/users/find
/users/{username}
```

And you are sending the route to say for example

```
/users/find
```

But laravel thinks its being sent to

```
/users/{username}
```

And you aren't sending a parameter through

Comment: Either that or the ['username' => $reply->user->username]) is null.

Comment: The routes are there now !

Answer (score 0):

How does laravel know what to do with

```
   Route::get('/user/{username}', [
    'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
      'as' => 'profile.index',
]);
```

The URL you are being directed to after URL decoding is /users/{username}

Look at the docs for generating urls to named routes
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

```
    Route::get('user/{id}/profile',         ['as' => 'profile', function ($id) {
    //
}]);

    $url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

From the docs

Comment: Yes I needed to show more code here! But I found the problem I will post, I left some needed code out though , thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I have for sure left out a lot of needed code which would really help explain some things , but I did find the problem. It was actually a little higher up in the form. I posted the top part of the form and left it incorrect so I can show you what to correct.

In the top part of the form I have two places where I am trying to link this so when the user clicks the name or picture or any anchor it will route to the user's profile. In the route directory it looks like  :

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', [
  'uses' => '\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
  'as' => 'profile.index',
]);
```

So this here is what I pass through to get in the URL ~/user/firstuser.

But this line below was giving me a URL of ~/user/%7Busername%7D.The reason for that is that I am not passing the username through the route parameter. To simplify this just think of $status->user->username as the user->username. There is relationships from some models and that is why I have the $status in front.

So what we need to fix here is where I call the route(), everything needs to go in this.I closed it off early.

```
 href="{{ route('profile.index'), ['username' => $status->user->username] }}"
```

Here is the correct line.

```
 href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}"
```

Comment: There is obviously a lot more content I could show you like the controller with its method , but I just wanted to point out the main problem for others who may have this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem, but maybe someone will come in handy.

```php
Route::patch('/margin/update/{{id}}', 'MarginsController@update')->name('margin.update');
```

- and in view

```php
action="{{ route('admin.margin.update',  $margin->id) }}"
```

- in url received the link

denis.loc/admin/margin/update/4%7D <= i.e. 4%7D  instead of (int) "4"

Morality. Be careful, there must be one `{id}`, but i write two `{{id}}} in Route.